# Shockwave How Would I Start?

Tags: 3d, shockwave, racing

I was just wondering, how would I go about creating a browser based 3D racing game to be a shockwave game?

Any links and tutorials would be very helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tutorials: [Director Online](http://www.director-online.com/)

Lots of links by [Dean](http://www.deansdirectortutorials.com/resources/)

And the connoisseurs' mailing list, still alive: 
[direct-l](http://listserv.uark.edu/archives/direct-l.html)

regards